# Swift 3 subclassing OperationQueue

Tags: nsoperationqueue, swift3

I have some problem with migration my code to Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 4).

```
    import Foundation

    class MyOperationQueue: Foundation.OperationQueue {
    override func addOperation(_ op: Operation) {
    ....
    }
```

I'm receiving this two errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

```
override func addOperation(_ op: Foundation.Operation) {
    ....
}
```